# Woocommerce quantity range shipping price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set up shipping price like this:

1 - 5 qty for $60
6 - 10 qty for $90

How can I do this? So if someone buys 3 pieces from the product then is charged 60 for shipping, if 6 or more then 90.

The basic [qty] placeholder woocommerce provides can't do this and did not find any plugin that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ? Add following function in your active theme functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $qty =  $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    //error_log($qty);
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping'){
            // Between 1 and 5
            if($qty > 0 && $qty <= 5):
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = '60';
                // Between 6 and 10
            elseif($qty > 5 && $qty <= 10):
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = '90';
            else:
                // For over 10
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = '60';
            endif;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```